# Make the first row as the keys for hash for the next rows?

Tags: ruby, excel, parsing, hash

I am having a hard time figuring out how to make the next rows a hash with the key from the first row.

I have an array structured like this:

```
[["id", "name", "address"], [1, "James", "...."], [2, "John", "...."] ]
```

To be:

```
[{ id : 1, name: "James", address: "..."}, ...]
```

I used a gem "simple_xlsx_reader", I am extracting out only the first sheet.

```
wb.sheets.first.row
```

and got a similar array output from above.

thanks!

Comment: Logic is not clear. How is the third subarray and on involved? Is the excel part of any significance to your question?

Comment: A complete example, which would not be difficult to devise, would be much better. You should then show your desired output for that input. When you give examples, you should assign variables to all inputs (e.g., `arr = [["id",....]`) so readers can refer to those variables in comments and answers without having to define them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
arr = [["id", "name"], [1, "Jack"], [2, "Jill"]]

[arr.first].product(arr.drop 1).map { |a| a.transpose.to_h }
  #=> [{"id"=>1, "name"=>"Jack"}, {"id"=>2, "name"=>"Jill"}]
```

The steps:

```
b = [arr.first]
  #=> [["id", "name"]] 
c = arr.drop 1
  #=> [[1, "Jack"], [2, "Jill"]] 
d = b.product(c)
  #=> [[["id", "name"], [1, "Jack"]], [["id", "name"], [2, "Jill"]]] 
d.map { |a| a.transpose.to_h }
  #=> [{"id"=>1, "name"=>"Jack"}, {"id"=>2, "name"=>"Jill"}]
```

The first element of `d` passed to `map`'s block is:

```
a = d.first
  [["id", "name"], [1, "Jack"]]
```

The block calculation is therefore:

```
e = a.transpose
  #=> [["id", 1], ["name", "Jack"]] 
e.to_h
  #=> {"id"=>1, "name"=>"Jack"}
```

Comment: You can use `arr.drop(1)`.

Comment: Thanks, @sawa, I never seem to think of using that. Edited.

Comment: Typo, third line from bottom, should be `#=> [["id", 1], ["name", "Jack"]]`. Since you've already used _d_ this may cause confusion!

Comment: Thanks, @sagarpandya82. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're looking for:

```
arr = [["id", "name", "address"], [1, "James", "...."], [2, "John", "...."] ]

keys, *values = arr
values.map {|vals| keys.zip(vals).to_h }
```

`Enumerable#zip` takes two arrays (the receiver and the argument) and "zips" them together, producing an array of tuples (two-element arrays) e.g.:

```
keys = [ "foo", "bar", "baz" ]
values = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
p keys.zip(values)
# => [ [ "foo", 1 ], [ "bar", 2 ], [ "baz", 3 ] ]
```

`Array#to_h` takes an array of tuples and turns it into a hash.

If you're using a version of Ruby earlier than 2.1 you'll need to use `Hash[ *keys.zip(vals) ]` instead.

P.S. If you want symbol keys instead of string keys you'll want to perform that conversion before the `map`, e.g.:

```
keys = keys.map(&:to_sym)
```

Or, if you don't mind modifying the original array:

```
keys.map!(&:to_sym)
```

Comment: What are `key` and `vals`?

Comment: They're typos. Writing code on a phone isn't especially intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this very simple one line that make your work

```
 arr =[["id", "name", "address"], [1, "James", "add 1"], [2, "John", "add2"] ]
 arr.map {|a|  arr.first.zip(a).to_h unless a == arr.first }.compact
```